# Opening text files in an external folder - once again

Tags: android, file, external

Goal: to open a text or csv file previously placed in an external folder.  Below is some code cobbled together from reading many posts and discussions on Stack Overflow and in Android developer surrounding this task, including the very helpful response by Chris Stratton to a question in Stack Overflow by Rokas Devolikis. Permission for reading and writing to external files are in the manifest and granted at runtime. In the code, the `TextView` under `onCreate` shows "permission OK" before the `selectFile` button is activated. The first time running the app triggered an internal checkbox to OK accessing external files. All good.

On activating selectFile to open "numbers.txt" with an external file path, "myFile2", the catch is triggered and shows the textView "catch invoked". Yet the path, which is sent via the first textView shows the correct path to myFile2.  Files called "numbers.txt" have been placed in a number of directories including downloads, download, documents and movies. This snippet shows movies because it is unambiguous in its naming within the "my files" file system under internal storage on my Android devices.

If the String `mf` is changed to "myFile1"  the code runs fine and finds the internal file "numbers.text" giving the text message "file open." 
Stratton noted that openFileInput only works with private files, so I have commented out that approach (which worked with myFile1 but not with myFile2).

What am I missing in order to reach the visible external file system containing "numbers.txt" with an associated external path?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;

private void insertDummyWrapper() {
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
                TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.datatext);
                textView.setText("permission granted");
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WRITE_EXTERNAL Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.datatext);
        textView.setText("permission requested");
        return;
    }
    else {
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.datatext);
        textView.setText("permission OK");}

}
//end of onCreate code

public void selectFile(View view)  {

    String numfile = "numbers.txt";
    File myFile1 = new File(numfile);
    File myFile2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), numfile);
    //   Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), numfile);
    // Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), numfile);
     String mf = String.valueOf(myFile2);
    TextView tV = findViewById(R.id.nameView);
    tV.setText(mf);

    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(mf);
        //       FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(mf,MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        //      do stuff here
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.datatext);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf("file opened"));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.datatext);
        textView.setText("catch invoked");}
}
```

Comment: "the catch is triggered and shows the textView "catch invoked"" -- examine the Java stack trace in LogCat.

Comment: `to open a text or csv file previously placed in an external folder.`. Well tell full path please.

Comment: `FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(mf);`. Change to `FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(myFile2);`.

Comment: `Yet the path, which is sent via the first textView shows the correct path to myFile2.` ?? And you are not going to tell us which path that is?

Comment: `textView.setText("catch invoked");}`. That is not a good message. Change to `textView.setText("catch invoked: " + e.getMessage());`

Comment: `String mf = String.valueOf(myFile2);`. Better use `myFile2.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, greenapps.  I'll clean up my code according to your suggestions.  As I mentioned in my answer though, reaching out to this forum got me over the hump in that the code I posted actually works now without any changes.  It takes a sense of humor to stay sane in this enterprise doesn't it?   Thanks again.

Comment: I never looked into the LogCat before, CommonWare.  It will take some time to understand what is being shown there, but you're right that there's good intel in the Log.  Thanks for turning me on to that aspect of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Let me post an answer and then a comment in another box.  The code actually works as shown.  Perhaps trying to explain myself caused me to fix an earlier problem that didn't translate over to the code I displayed.  Bottom line is that I'm over this hump now, and that's the important part. :) Rex